# Is there a more efficient approach to training an embedding layer in PyTorch for speaker ID conversion?

Tags: pytorch

What are some ideas to improve embedding layer performance?

Currently, an embedding layer is used to convert speaker ids (int) to vectors with a size of 256. During training, the speaker IDs (maximum number is 6) are sent in a batch size of 6 in a random sequence, then the embedding layer outputs a tensor of (6, 256), which is then forwarded to the [GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) model that generates a spectrogram representing the speaker's voice.

During inferencing, the same is done, except usually only one speaker id is sent to the embed layer (returns [1, 256]).

So essentially the embed weights are trained on the loss, ([Mel spectrograms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mel-frequency_cepstrum), features, etc.) during the backwards pass. However, I am getting speaker leakage during inference.

I thought of using an [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory), but they're mainly good at sequential data from what I know of them, and as the sequence of the IDs in batches are at random during training, I don't see how it would benefit. Fully connected layers after the embed layer was another consideration I made.

It was written using PyTorch by the way.

Comment: Is "Speaker ID" [literal](https://cloud.google.com/speaker-id)?